# Make markLabel take up multiple lines

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a MUI Slider that I am trying to get styled the way I want. I can't seem to figure out how to get the markLabel CSS for the slider to break my text up into multiple lines. I'm using the slider as a "Strongly Agree, Agree, nuetral, Disagree, Strongly Disagree" selector, and the text on smaller screens just stacks on top of each other. I have tried setting the width of markLabel, as well as using overflowWrap and break-word. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read up on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to avoid getting your question closed. You need to show us your code, otherwise we will not be able to help you. You can edit your question to add your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and wanted to show a date range for every Slider mark spreaded over the two lines.
[image: Slider with two lines mark labels]

With the following code I could display the first date -- above the slider and the second date -- below the slider.

```
// populate marks array in a for-loop
    ...    
    const l = (
      <pre style={{ fontFamily: "inherit" }}>
        {date1}..
        <br />
        ..{date2}
      </pre>
    );
    arr.push( {
      value: i, label: l,
    } );
    ...

// in addition I have styled the mark labels with the following CSS:
markLabel: {
  whiteSpace: "normal",
  overflowWrap: "normal",
  top: -36,
  lineHeight: 2,
},
```

In your case, you can use `<pre>` and `<br/>` tags for the label property of the marks array and then vary *top* and *lineHeight* CSS-attributes to position the two-line labels where you need them.